# Can't reinstall Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I deleted Python's directory, now I can't reinstall it, it tries to upgrade.

I deleted `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Python`

I looked at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE` but there was no Python.

platform: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: What is Your operating system ?

Comment: Windows 7 @user3799089

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows OS You should go to Your Control Panel and chose Uninstall a Program. Then You should find Your current Python installation and remove it with all dependencies.

Under Ubuntu You have to go to the terminal and execute command `sudo apt-get remove python3*` for Python 3.n versions.

Comment: I deleted Python directory, uninstaller not working

Comment: Did You checked in the installed programm list ? Haven't You see it there ?

Comment: It says "No Python 3.8 installation detected."

Comment: Make directory like was before and put there python files (from any repository) and try uninstall it.